# Moving a foreground image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a foreground image with CSS so it overlaps a little with a background image. I simply cannot seem to get the foreground image to move anywhere and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction? See my [fiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/jsykes/tts635xg/).

html:

```
<img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/aUYcExsGuRaw7PLGmAmXubt1dfG.jpg" style="-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,   from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))"
    width="auto" height="400" class="backgroundImg">
<div class="frontImg">
<img  src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w150/2i0JH5WqYFqki7WDhUW56Sg0obh.jpg" class="" height="300" width="auto">
 </div>
```

css:

```
body{
 background: black;
}
.background{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.frontImg{
  position: absolute;
  left:200;
  top:500;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the unit (%, em, px, etc.) of height and width of `.frontImg`

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.backgroundImg {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}
.frontImg{
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  top:100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/aUYcExsGuRaw7PLGmAmXubt1dfG.jpg" width="auto" height="400" class="backgroundImg">
<div class="frontImg">
  <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w150/2i0JH5WqYFqki7WDhUW56Sg0obh.jpg" height="300" width="auto">
</div>
```

Additionaly you can do some optimization: You can move the css from style attributes to your css file, to get a clean html structure without any inline css.

And i think there is a typo on your CSS - replace `.background` with `.backgroundImg`.

Answer (score 3):

You're lacking measurement unit name. Try `200px` instead of `200`, `500px` instead of `500`.

Without measurement unit your style simply got ignored by the browser.